# Problemas con carosel en bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```js
// Carousel Auto-Cycle
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 8000
    })
  });
```

```css
#myCarousel {
    position: center;
    padding: 2em;
}
/* Thumbnail Box */
.caption h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    }
        .btn.btn-mini {
            font-size: 18px;
            background-color: #00bcb3;
            color: #ffffff;
            }
/* Carousel Control */
.control-box {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .carousel-control{
        background: #000000;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 34px;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 25px;
        opacity: 100;
        padding: 4px 10px 0px;
        position: static;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 
                <div class="item">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div><!-- /Slide2 --> 
                <div class="item">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div><!-- /Slide3 --> 
            </div>

            <div class="control-box">                            
                <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
                <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
            </div><!-- /.control-box -->   

        </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

    </div><!-- /.col -->          
    </div><!-- /.row --> 
    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

Hola estoy queriendo armar un carousel como [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096131/bootstrap-carousel-moves-slightly-up-then-down-again-when-scrolling) en boostraps 4 pero no me funciona. alguien sabe si en boostraps 4 se pueden seguir usando este tipo de carouseles??? porque copio el codigo tal cual al ejemplo y en el 3 anda, pero cuando vinculo hoja de estilo y script del 4 no funciona. Muy raro la verdad!

Comment: En Bootstrap 4 a comparación del Bootstrap 3 han cambiado algunas cosas, no es tan simple como cambiar la versión y ya debes mirar en la documentación de Bootstrap 4 como se hace el carousel, si quieres que te ayudemos debes mostrar el código que has intentado

Comment: Hola el codigo con el que intente hacer el carousel es el de la pagina que adjunte arriba, si había leído que habían cambiado algunas cosas.

Comment: Debes añadir el código a tu pregunta en un snippet para poderlo ejecutar

Comment: ahí agregue el código.

Answer (score 2):

Como te decía para que el **carousel** funcione debes ir a la documentación de [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) y leer que estructura se debe seguir, he agregado las clases que Bootstrap requiere para que el **carousel** funcione.

veo que hay problemas con algunos estilos, imagino que es por lo mismo te recomiendo leer la documentación para ver los cambios, saludos.

```js
// Carousel Auto-Cycle
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 8000
    })
  });
```

```css
#myCarousel {
    position: center;
    padding: 2em;
}
/* Thumbnail Box */
.caption h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    }
        .btn.btn-mini {
            font-size: 18px;
            background-color: #00bcb3;
            color: #ffffff;
            }
/* Carousel Control */
.control-box {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .carousel-control{
        background: #000000;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 34px;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 25px;
        opacity: 100;
        padding: 4px 10px 0px;
        position: static;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                            <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                            <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                            <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                            <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 

            <div class="carousel-item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div><!-- /Slide2 --> 

            <div class="carousel-item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div><!-- /Slide3 --> 
        </div>

        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

    </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

</div><!-- /.col -->          
</div><!-- /.row --> 
</div><!-- /.container -->
```